# trim leading zeros in impala

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

I have two sorts of accounts number, all of which are strings:
some of them have `leading zeros`, others have been imported properly and do not have leading zeros;

How can I get rid of the leading zeros without trimming account numbers that are normal?

the ones with leading zeros are somewhat:
`0000012345678`

Those without leading zeros are:
`1345678`

How can I do that in Impala without trimming all the account numbers?From what I have seen there are always 5 leading zeros in those records with leading zeros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST( "0000012345678"  AS INT);
```

OR

```
SELECT regexp_replace( "0000012345678","^0+(?!$)","")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('0000012345678', '^0*', '') AS number_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `substr()`

```
select case when left(accountno)='00000' then substr(accountno,6,length(accountno)-5)
else accountno end
from yourtablename
```